# Viewing menu.lst from another system

Tags: dual-boot

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 from a memory stick.  I want to see the list of operating systems on /dev/sda.  I looked at grub.cfg but the information I need is deeply embedded in that file and difficult to interpret.  Is there a way to see the actual boot menu that would be displayed when I boot up the system on /dev/sda? The problem came up because I can't boot into Linux directly at the moment (the computer goes right into Windows), and I don't want to fiddle with the grub configuration unless I'm very sure of what I'm doing.

The information I'm really looking for is the number of each OS on /dev/sda so that I can set GRUB_DEFAULT correctly.